# What's the best way to repeat the same image multiple times in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So my documents structure looks like this:

```
<p>Repeat image 5 times after this paragraph </p>

<p>Repeat the same image 25 times after this paragraph </p>

<p>Repeat the image again 100 times after this paragraph </p>
```

The way I add the images right now is by using a script tag after each p element and using document.write inside a for loop in that script.

I want to keep all of JavaScript and jQuery separately from HTML. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You haven't posted any javascript code..

Comment: Well, I'm using JADE as my HTML preprocessor and this can be done very easily, read here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/. I can provide you with more information about jade if you want to. Other way would be if you dont want to see an JS code in your HTML file you can include these files instead :D

Comment: I'm just going to mention this here before anyone says something like *"Don't use document.write()"*. Using it for this case is completely valid, and is the correct way to use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep JavaScript out of the HTML file, I would suggest you to create a separate file with your JavaScript(.js file) code and then reference to it from your.html file where you want to use that JavaScript, like this:

`<script src="location_of_your_javascript_file/file_name.js"></script>`

Then in your .html file add to each paragraph tag an ID attribute that is unique for each parahraph tag, like this:

```
<p id='unique_id'>....</p>
<p id='unique_id2'>....</p>
```

Then you could write something like this to your .js file:

```
function appendPhotosToParagraph(paragraph_id, how_many_times):
    var paragraph = document.getElementById(paragraph_id);
    for (var i = 0; i < how_many_times; i++) {
        paragraph.innerHTML += "<img src='location_of_your_photo_file/file_name.jpg'";
    }

appendPhotosToParagraph('unique_id', 5);
appendPhotosToParagraph('unique_id2', 25);
```

You basically create a function which you will call on each paragraph. Functions finds paragraph element by the unique id and assigns it to the `paragraph` variable. Then it uses for loop to loop for `how_many_times` every time appending `<img>` tag to the existing content of the paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

Css? 
if Image size is 100*100px

1. add div
2. set background for it (image)
3. set width = 100px
4. set height 500px (100 * times u need to repeat)

   p.repeat25 + div.image {
      width: 100px;
      height: 2500px;
      background: url(image.png);
   }

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I know, there's no way to do such thing. You can try to use Angular.JS, which provides some "loop features" inside HTML, based on a Javascript array.
e.g:

```js
angular.module('testing',[])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.paragraphs = ["p1","p2","p3"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testing">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <p ng-repeat="p in paragraphs">
      {{ p }}
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Replace paragraphs for images.